# vstest.console.exe - Specify output file location via command line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vstest, vstest.console

I'm running test on vstest.console.exe. How to specify the location of results file?

```
vstest.console.exe [TestLocation] /Logger:trx /Platform:x64 /InIsolation /Tests:[Testname]
```

**SOLUTION: Run tests from the folder, where I want my "TestResults" appear**

Comment: Do you use TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the location of result file can not be changed in vstest.console.exe command line.

If you are using TFS, you could consider add tasks such as [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) in your build definition, to copy files to target folder.